# How do I fix irregular surfaces

Tags: modeling

enter image description here[image]I already read some post related to this issue, did what they say but I still having the same problem. As you see in the picture the surface of my mesh has many irregularities (cheeks). I tried fixing quads so I did delete all the cheek area and modeled again but the irregularity still appearing, It is a ri[image]gged mesh so I don't think is a problem with doubles. Can somebody help me to fix this ?

enter image description here

Comment: Could you share the wireframes, I suspect these irregularities are poles.

Comment: Hi Samir. Sorry I'm not an expert on this. Can you tell me please where can I find such wireframes?

Comment: In the viewport change the shading mode to wireframe and take a screenshot.

Comment: this is what happened when I applied wireframe. All the mesh is a disaster. Picture above

Comment: Do not use the wireframe modifier, delete it. Change the viewport mode from material to wireframe this is found in the viewport header.

Comment: To change the viewport mode click on the little sphere at the bottom of the viewport to the right of the "Object mode" button.

Comment: Sorry. I just posted the picture again.

Comment: No problem. It seems the artifacts are indeed from poles. A pole is when more than 4 edges meet at a single point. If you want to get rid of a pole you have to think of a different way to model that area or move it to a less visible place.

Comment: To show the topology of the mesh please enter Edit mode of it, set the shading mode of the viewport to Solid and take a screenshot. It's really hard to see what's going on there as the back of the mesh and the front interfer with each other. As to "irregularities" it could be everything starting from bad topology and up to wrong weights (as this is rigged model).

Comment: Hi Mr. Zak. Picture just posted as you ask above.

Comment: Well, that looks like topology problem. See [face topology](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/FaceTopology) on polycount for references and guides. There are a lot of edge loops which don't follow the curvature of the face muscles which will eventually show artifacts (either when animated or even without that). You might want to retopologize that, at least that area.

Comment: Yep. I can see what you mean. thank you. do you think  this (I mean retopo)  will not affect the rig?

Comment: It will as you'll change vertices which had weights applied which is used by rig (this means you will have to paint weights there once more, hence I wrote *only that area"). I don't think I know any workaround - to avoid that when topology isn't good enough and rig is already done.

Comment: I did retopo but imperfections still. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one vertex on each cheek with 8 edges going into it, that's just bad modelling. I recommend CG Cookie's tutorial: https://vimeo.com/3835507

Comment: Try to add more substance to your answer besides the link. If think link goes down, your answer will not be as usefull

Comment: Thanks for the CG Cookie tutorial. For 10 replies: I'm new in this Forum. Still hard for me figure things out yet but I will look into your recommendations. Thanks